# Inconsistencies in tag colours on some meta sites

Tags: bug, tags, design, per-site-meta, full-sites

On a few places on some child meta sites, the "other" tags (that is, ones like [chat](/questions/tagged/chat), not the moderator-only ones like [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), and not the required ones like [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)), are blue, while in most other places, they are grey.

This appears to be the same on all sites with unique Meta themes (only [full-sites](/questions/tagged/full-sites), I believe), but not on meta.stackexchange.com itself (where you are now) or other sites with the "default" theme.

Here is a list of places where they appear blue that I've found so far:

- /tags, in the legend/key for the colours
- When asking a question in the Tags field

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like on Code Golf - the two different colours are highlighted in pink:

[image: Screenshot of tag colour inconsistencies]

The grey ones are too similar in style to the required tags, and aren't distinguishable from tags referring to the main site (`[meta-tag:foo] [tag:foo]`). The difference is irrelevant here because there is no main site for non-meta tags to link to, but on Code Golf it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0JBe.png)).

The blue ones don't match the theme of the relevant sites, and I'm assuming they're using the default network colour.

IMO they should be the same as the general accent colour on meta (that's red on SO for example).

Comment: There's also an inconsistency on the picture, as freehand red circles appear as pink square here... bug-report?

Answer (score 1):

This is behaviour specific to the /tags page on a meta site.

On all meta sites (designed or not) tags have a greyish background, while the standard way to represent a tag is the blueish background you see used on that [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) tag in your screenshot, and used on many "main" sites such as Meta Stack Exchange, or [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/)

Designed sites can use different background colours for tags on the main site, for example [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) uses a greyish background, while [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions) uses an almost transparent background.

So the real "bug" here is that this [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) tag is not using the same style as the other tags on a meta site.